# How to access or grant based on custom conditions

Tags: spring

Assume i want to grant an user based on certain conditions not based on roles or permissions or anything.

Assume a user hits the url /getAllOrders. i need to give access if satisfies certain conditions.

In that case, i am not sure how to do it. I checked and come across AccessDecisionVoter and not sure whether it will be suitable for it and also don't know how to implement it.

1. can someone suggest whethere AccessDecisionVoter would be the right option ?
2. looking for working sample code snippet which uses AccessDecisionVoter

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller you can make use of `@PreAuthorize` on your handler method and call a method that you declare inside a subclass of `SecurityExpressionRoot`. You need to do a bit of configuration to register your `SecurityExpressionRoot`inside of a `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration`

In your Controller:

```
@PreAuthorize("isMyCustomConditionMet()")
@GetMapping("/getAllOrders")
public String allOrders(Model model) {
     model.addAttribute("orders", orderService.getAllOrders());
     return "orders";
}
```

In a configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class CustomMethodSecurityConfig extends 
GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return new CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    }


}
```

This is the class we are instantiating above:

```
public class CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler extends DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler {

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionOperations createSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication, MethodInvocation methodInvocation) {

        CustomSecurityExpressionRoot root = new CustomSecurityExpressionRoot(authentication);
        root.setThis(methodInvocation.getThis());
        root.setPermissionEvaluator(getPermissionEvaluator());
        root.setTrustResolver(new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl());
        root.setRoleHierarchy(getRoleHierarchy());
        root.setDefaultRolePrefix("ROLE_");
        return root;

    }

}
```

This is where you define your customer logic:

```
public class CustomSecurityExpressionRoot extends SecurityExpressionRoot 
    implements MethodSecurityExpressionOperations {

    private Object filterObject;
    private Object returnObject;
    private Object target;

    public CustomSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication) {
        super(authentication);
    }

    public boolean isMyCustomConditionMet() {
        return [INSERT YOUR LOGIC HERE!];
    }

    @Override
    public void setFilterObject(Object filterObject) {
        this.filterObject = filterObject;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getFilterObject() {
        return filterObject;
    }

    @Override
    public void setReturnObject(Object returnObject) {
        this.returnObject = returnObject;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getReturnObject() {
         return returnObject;
    }

    void setThis(Object target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getThis() {
        return target;
    }
}
```

Comment: The method is going to be common for all methods and don't want to add annotation in every method. How about Access Voter approach ?